# Can single method in java returns any one of float or Integer?

Tags: java

This is java coding, here I should write only one methods with one input parameter( which may be float or integer). And I need to set the dynamic return type either float or integer depends upon the input parameter datatype.

If I provide input like this 5 or 5.0, my return value should be like this 5, same like
If I provide input like this 5.1, my return value should be like this 5.1.

```
public static float random_val(float p_value)
{
    float l_value = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    l_value  = p_value * Math.round(Math.floor((rand.nextFloat()*8)+2));
    System.out.println("F");
    return l_value;
}
```

In this coding, I can't make the dynamic return and input type.

Is there any option to achieve this?

Ex1: System.out.println(random_val(5));
output:35

Ex2: System.out.println(random_val(5.0));
output:55

Ex3: System.out.println(random_val(5.1));
output:38.5

Comment: You could take a Number as argument, test its type, and then return a Number (which would be either an Integer or a Float). But that would be bad design, IMO. You should just have two different methods: one for floats, and one for ints.

Comment: just overload the methods

Comment: *"If I provide input like this 5 or 5.0, my return value should be like this 5"* `5` and `5.0` in Java source code are **very different things**. The first is an  `int`. The second is a `double`. (Neither of them is a `float`.) The requirement that you treat a `double` that happens to contain a whole number as though it were an `int` makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> here I should write only one methods with one input parameter...And I need to set the dynamic return type either float or integer depends upon the input parameter datatype.

You can't do that in Java. Java methods don't have dynamic return types (or dynamic parameter types, for that matter; *there's generic type parameters, but let's not go there*). Your method as shown **always** accepts a `float`, and **always** returns a `float`. That `float` may or may not represent a whole number, but it's still a `float`.

You have three options, but really without a **strong** reason to go another way, the first option is the way to go:

#### Overloading

You can define two methods with the same name as long as their signatures are different in  some way other than the return type. In this case, you could define

```
public static float random_val(float f_value) {
    // ....
}
```

and

```
public static int random_val(int i_value) {
    // ....
}
```

This is called *overloading* the method. The above works because although there are two `random_val` methods, only one of them takes a `float` parameter while the other takes an `int` parameter, so they have distinct signatures.

It is, technically, two methods. But we usually call it one overloaded method.

#### Generic method

Alternately, you could use a *generic method* that accepts anything that extends [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), which is the base class of both `Float` and `Integer`, the boxing types for `float` and `int`:

```
public static <T extends Number> T random_val(T value) {
    // ...do calculation based on whether `value` is a Float
    // or an Integer, fail if it's another kind of number (Double,
    // Byte, ...), return either a Float or an Integer
    if (value instanceof Float) {
        Float result = /*...*/;
        return result;
    }
    if (value instanceof Integer) {
        Integer result = /*...*/;
        return result;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("value must be Float or Integer");
}
```

there may be a better generic way of doing that switching, but with `float` (technically `Float`) and `int` (technically `Integer`), I'm not coming up with it.

This probably isn't the right thing when dealing with `float` and `int`, but it does meet the requirement of a single method rather than two.

#### Old-fashioned pre-generics way using `Number` specifically

Another alternative — and it's not a good one — is to use `Number` the old-fashioned way. That would look like this:

```
public static Number random_val(Number value) {
    // ...do calculation based on whether `value` is a Float
    // or an Integer, fail if it's another kind of number (Double,
    // Byte, ...), return either a Float or an Integer
    if (value instanceof Float) {
        Float result = /*...*/;
        return result;
    }
    if (value instanceof Integer) {
        Integer result = /*...*/;
        return result;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("value must be Float or Integer");
}
```

**This is not a good idea,** but it does meet the requirement of a single method handling both types, through boxing them and using the base class.

---

Side note: Use cases for `float` are few and far between, because `float` is a **very** imprecise type. For floating-point numbers, usually `double` is the thing to reach for (or `BigDecimal` for certain classes of operations).

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear reply, but can you please see the Ex2: If I give 5.0 as input, it should returns only integer value like 5. Is there any optional way?

Comment: @VivekHarry: As I said above, your method as written both accepts and returns a `float`, **always**, never an `int`. The presence or absense of `.0` in the output is neither here nor there, that's just a feature of how the number is being converted to a string for output. If all you care about is the string output, look at [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Comment: Thank you all friends, finally I got the output by using this reference. special thankx to @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 4):

you can use method Overloading..

```
public static float random_val(float p_value)
{
    float l_value = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    l_value  = p_value * Math.round(Math.floor((rand.nextFloat()*8)+2));
    System.out.println("F");
    return l_value;
}

public static int random_val(int p_value)
{
    int l_value = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    l_value  = p_value * Math.round(Math.floor((rand.nextFloat()*8)+2));
    System.out.println("F");
    return l_value;
}
```

**EDIT**
use a single method to compute result and return value.
in the caller method, check whether the value returned is an integer or not.
you can use a diff way to check if its integer or not. it goes something like this:

```
public static float random_val(float p_value)
    {
        float l_value = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        l_value  = p_value * Math.round(Math.floor((rand.nextFloat()*8)+2));
        System.out.println("F");
        return l_value;
    }

    float result = random_val(5.0);
    //check for result, if it is integer
    if(Math.floor(result)==result){
       // is integer, make sure the values of computation don't exceed int's range
       int r = (int)result;
       use integer value
    }
    else{
       //use float value
    }
```

Comment: Depending on interpretation, that technically violates the *"should write only one methods"* requirement, though for Java, that is the best way to do it, so you still get my up-vote.

Comment: Can you please see the EX2:  ------- System.out.println(random_val(5.0)); output:55 . How can I get this? And one more thing, I will be calling the method dynamically like (5 or 5.0 or 5.8) like this. If I call the input parameter like 5.0, my return value should bot be 5.0, it should be integer.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function with signature something similar to this,

> public static Object random_val(Object p_value)

Let's assume that you are writing this function for Calc class, here is the code for the class (Please note the usage of Float and Integer).

```
public class Calc {

    public static Object random_val(Object p_value) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (p_value instanceof Float)
        {
            Float f = (Float)p_value;
            //Some calculation...
            return f;
        }
        if (p_value instanceof Integer)
        {
            Integer i = (Integer)p_value;
            //Some calculation...
            return i;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal type passed...");
    }
}
```

The invocation or caller code should use this function something like this,

```
Float fv = (Float)Calc.random_val(new Float(5.2));
//Do some work with fv
Integer iv = (Integer)Calc.random_val(new Integer(2));
//Do some work with iv
```